# Get unique sheet from 2 separate sheets

Tags: excel

I have a single Excel document with 2 sheets. The first sheet contains "active" clients and the 2nd "inactive clients" but we want to merge both into a 3rd sheet "all clients". We want to ensure that there isn't any multiple rows. Column A in both sheets is the "identifier" which is a 16 digit numeric value. Both sheets have the same columns so effectively I want to match column A in both sheets and return the entire row if it's not found yet. There is around 1.2 million rows combined in both sheets, hence why I cannot just copy and paste them into a single document.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Excel not designed for work with `1.2 million rows`, you should consider about migrating your data in database. Access would be the easiest way. But if you still what to do it in excel (if total count of unique clients less that 1mln), copy data _by portions_ from each sheet to third sheet (say by 100K rows) and then, after pasting new portion of data, use [remove duplicates](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/remove-duplicates.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good advice in the comments but because even after removal of duplicates there may not be enough rows to accommodate the de-duped list I would suggest starting by determining how many duplicates and deciding which list to delete any from (or you might end up with an incomplete combined list but no practical way to extend it). In both sheets add a column with:

```
=MATCH(A1,Sheet2/1!A:A,0)
```

(Sheet2 name for one, Sheet1 name for the other) and copy down to suit.

Then check the de-duped combination number less than 1,048,576 in total. If more they won't fit on a single sheet without an additional set of columns and even if less a database is to be preferred, though not obligatory, with the Excel version possibly convenient for upload.